# How can I minimize the use of power button on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, sleep, power, hibernate

I want to save the power button on my [Laptop](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/pk/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s340-15iil) by using it the minimum number of times. I have to use my laptop several times on most days. On some days, I don't use it all.

The best strategy I have figured out yet is to set my laptop to sleep when I close the lid and it wakes up whenever I open the lid. This method doesn't use the power button at all. The problem with this strategy is that the battery slowly drains on sleep mode, although it can last at least 4-5 days like this. When using this method, I restart it once or twice a week to give it a fresh start.

The second best method I have been using often is to hibernate it when not in use. This way, I have to use the power button once every cycle, but it doesn't use the battery at all.

Is there any better method? Are there any pros or cons of these two methods that I have missed?

Comment: Does your PC Supports open lid to power on?

Comment: I am not sure. How do I find out? I couldn't find any such setting at the first look.